# Asymmetric "Jurassic Park"-esque 2 player game

Tags: identify-this-game, two-player

I remember playing a game at a board game event, but can't find its name for the life of me.

Two players only. One plays as a Velociraptor mother (and her younglings), and the other plays as a dinosaur hunter. The hunter tries to capture as many dinosaurs as possible and kill the mother, while the Velociraptor tries to escape with her young.

The box is on the smaller side, about 20x5x5cm.

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could it be [Raptor](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/177639/raptor)? From BoardGameGeek:

> Mamma Raptor has escaped from her run and laid her eggs in the park. A
> team of scientists must neutralize her and capture the baby raptors
> before they run wild into the forest.
>
> Raptor is a card driven boardgame with tactical play and some double
> guessing. Players use their cards to move their pawns (scientists on
> one side, Mother and baby raptors on the other) on the board. Every
> round, the player who played the lowest ranked card can use the
> corresponding action, while his opponent has movement / attack points
> equal to the difference between the two cards values. The scientists
> can use fire, can move by jeep on the tracks, and can even call for
> reinforcements, while the mamma raptor can hide in the bushes, yell to
> frighten the scientists, and call for her babies.

Comment: Likely, assuming those box dimensions aren't correct!